# How to join fields of a table with others from another table using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables which I would like to join. Here they are:

Table 01:

```
ID | Name | Surname | Code1
01 | AAAA |  XXXXX  |  1234
02 | BBBB |  YYYYY  |  1597
03 | CCCC |  PPPPP  |  2134
04 | DDDD |  QQQQQ  |  9514
05 | EEEE |  RRRRR  |  8797
06 | FFFF |  SSSSS  |  5467
 . |   .  |    .    |   .
 . |   .  |    .    |   .
 . |   .  |    .    |   .
19 | SSSS |  ZZZZZ  |  3571, etc.
```

Table 02:

```
Code1 | Code2 | Index
 1234 |  2134 |  971
 1234 |  9514 |  942
 1234 |  8797 |  912
  .   |   .   |   .
  .   |   .   |   .
  .   |   .   |   .
 1234 |  5467 |  113
 1597 |  3364 |  902
 1597 |  8797 |  834, etc.
```

First of all I tried following select:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    a.surname,
    (SELECT
        b.index
    FROM
        table02 b
    WHERE
        b.code1 = 1234
    AND
        b.code2 = a.code1) index
FROM
    table01 a
WHERE
    a.code1 in (2134, 9514, 8797,..., 5467) // all rows where code2 from table02 is related to code1 = 1234 as we can see in the table.
ORDER BY index DESC
```

But this didn't give me the expect result. The right result should be:

```
ID   Name   Surname   Index
03 | CCCC |  PPPPP  |  971   // which has code1 in table01 and code2 in table02 = 2134
04 | DDDD |  QQQQQ  |  942   // which has code1 in table01 and code2 in table02 = 9514
05 | EEEE |  RRRRR  |  912   // which has code1 in table01 and code2 in table02 = 8797
   |   .  |    .    |   .
   |   .  |    .    |   .
   |   .  |    .    |   .
06 | FFFF |  SSSSS  |  113   // which has code1 in table01 and code2 in table02 = 5467
```

Maybe a solution with INNER JOIN would work, but with that I can't begin anything without help. I've tried something, but no result was displayed at all. :-(

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This should help: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic join.  I recommend reading up on [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins)

```
Select t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Surname, t2.index
FROM table01 t1
INNER JOIN table02 t2
 on t1.code1 = t2.code2
```

What this says is return all records from table 1 and table 2 where the code1 field in table 1 match the code2 field in table 2.  displaying the ID, name and surname from table one and the index from table 2.

- code1 Records in table 1 that do not have a record in code2 of table2 will be excluded
- code2 records in table 2 that do not have a record in code1 of table1 will be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

With an inner join

```
SELECT  a.id, a.name, a.surname
FROM tabla1 a 
INNER JOIN tabla2 b ON (a.code1 = b.code2)
WHERE a.code1 in (2134, 9514, 8797,..., 5467) 
ORDER BY a.name DESC
```

Comment: Pretty sure the join is a.code1 = b.code2 otherwise ID's 01 and 02 should be listed in expected results.  also comment in result set says: `// which has code1 in table01 and code2 in table02 = 2134`

Answer (score 0):

Simplify (whitout join):

```
SELECT
    table01.id,
    table01.name,
    table01.surname,
    table02.index //from the second table
FROM
    table01
    table02

    WHERE
        table02.code1 = 1234
    AND
        table02.code2 = table01.code1
ORDER BY table01.index DESC
```

(add a group by id if you want a single row per id)